# Controlling 5 DC motors with Arduino

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-mega, motor, shields

I am looking to purchase the correct hardware to be able to control 5 DC Motors from an Arduino (UNO preferred, MEGA if necessary).

The Specs of the Motors are as follows: 12 V nominal, 3 → 12 V dc, 794 gcm, 100 rpm, 0.394 W

What would be your recommendations for how to set this up? As I am fairly new to circuitry a circuit diagram would be helpful along with the recommendation of what shield or drivers to use. Thank You

Comment: Do you need constant speeds or variable?  Do you need to sense the speeds?  Do you need reverse as well as forward rotation?

Comment: Constant speeds. I do need reverse and forward

Comment: Since youre new to circuitry - you should know an  actual  circuit for this is not hard to make. Its not something I'd buy a shield  for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are currently no expansion boards (shields) for the Arduino platform that are designed to do what you're asking of it. At most you'll find shields that can support up to 2 maybe 3 motors. My recommendation for a beginner would be to experiment with a breakout board like this one: https://www.sparkfun.com/products/9457 It's compact and can easily control 2 of the motors you need, three together and you could control up to 6.

Comment: would I need any other components to work with these?

Comment: No, nothing beyond a little soldering equipment, this blidr tutorial may help you, http://bildr.org/2012/04/tb6612fng-arduino/ . Note that for the motor direction pins on this breakout, if all your motors are spinning in a fixed direction, you could connect the proper pins to +5v and Ground without having to sacrifice more digital pins for it.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use the shield that is directly attachable to the Uno, for example: http://playground.arduino.cc/Main/AdafruitMotorShield. So everything you need is Uno, this shield and motors. No soldering.